# Scala PlayFramework don't wait for response just store in database

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0

In the code below every service, implements check trait which returns the boolean.I am new to scala so wanted to know that Is there a way to add some service in here which returns the boolean immediately (response for this service will not be used so it can return true every time) and works in the background for a populating database, while loop completes and return the result to the requester.

```
requestedChecks.keys.par.foreach(serviceName => {
    if(requestedChecks(serviceName) == 1 && checkList.contains(serviceName)) {
        data += (serviceName -> initializeService(serviceName).check(mapForService))
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this it's the proposal of @mrfyda which was also my thought:

```
import play.api.libs.concurrent.Execution.Implicits._
import scala.concurrent.Future

Future {
    requestedChecks.keys.par.foreach(serviceName => {
        if(requestedChecks(serviceName) == 1 && checkList.contains(serviceName)) {
            data += (serviceName -> initializeService(serviceName).check(mapForService))
        }
    })
}

Ok(view.html.index()) // or whatever you response looks like
```

Comment: Thank you. This is working perfectly. sascha10000 & @mrfyda